# How to find accumulator matrix for line in an image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, octave, hough-transform

I am a newbie in the field of CV and IP. I was writing the HoughTransform algorithm for finding line.I am not getting what is wrong with this code in which i m trying to find the accumulator array

```
numRowsInBW = size(BW,1);
numColsInBW = size(BW,2);

%length of the diagonal of image
D = sqrt((numRowsInBW - 1)^2 + (numColsInBW - 1)^2);
%number of rows in the accumulator array
nrho = 2*(ceil(D/rhoStep)) + 1;
%number of cols in the accumulator array
ntheta = length(theta);

H = zeros(nrho,ntheta);

%this means the particular pixle is white 
%i.e the edge pixle
[allrows allcols] = find(BW == 1);

for i = (1 : size(allrows))
    y = allrows(i);
    x = allcols(i);
    for th = (1 : 180)
        d = floor(x*cos(th) - y*sin(th));
        H(d+floor(nrho/2),th) += 1;
    end
end
```

I m applying this for a simple image [image]
I m getting this result[image]

But this is expected [image]

I am not able to find the mistake.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. The main issue is here:

```
ntheta = length(theta);
% ...
for i = (1 : size(allrows))
    % ...
    for th = (1 : 180)
        d = floor(x*cos(th) - y*sin(th));
        % ...
```

`th` seems to be an angle in degrees. `cos(th)` is meaningless. Instead, use [`cosd`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Trigonometry.html#XREFcosd) and `sind`.

Another issue is that `th` iterates from 1 to 180, but there is no guarantee that `ntheta` is 180. So, loop as follows instead:

```
for i = 1 : size(allrows)
    % ...
    for j = 1 : numel(theta)
        th = theta(j);
        % ...
```

and use `th` as the angle, and `j` as the index into `H`.

Finally, given your image and your expected output, you should apply some edge detection first (Canny, for example). Maybe you already did this?